# How to access ServiceSaleItem class record in netsuite suitetalk webservice

Tags: web-services, netsuite

Please provide the solution to access ServiceSaleItem class records from netsuite suitetalk web service

Answer (score 0):

- At the top of the class, define an import for the ServiceSaleItem Type.

  `import com.netsuite.webservices.lists.accounting.ServiceSaleItem`
- Depending on your business use case, you could now run a search in NetSuite to fetch the item as you would do for other types and then you could do something like this

  ```
  if(searchRecord instanceof ServiceSaleItem) {
      ServiceSaleItem itemRec = (ServiceSaleItem) searchRecord;                
  }
  ```

Comment: if(searchRecord instanceof ServiceSaleItem)

Comment: if(searchRecord instanceof ServiceSaleItem) please tell about the method for access all the fields from this class.